# cross compile net snmp for arm processor

Tags: linux, cpu, arm

i just want to cross compile net snmp for arm cortex a9 (cyclone v soc altera).
can anybody tell me how to proceed step by step?in custum board my ram is 4 gb and sd card 8 gb .i want to compile full version .

Answer (score 0):

Not tested with this particular package and architecture but generally it should work as long as configuration needed (e.g. Kernel version) is not too odd:

1. Get Buildroot from https://buildroot.org/
2. Install the required packages from https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#requirement-mandatory
3. Do `make menuconfig`, choose your architecture, Linux Kernel and whether you want to compile with glibc or uclibc, dynamically or statically and such. Exit (Esc-Esc) and confirm to save the settings.
4. `make toolchain`
5. `make netsnmp`